# jQuery: How to get the first “td” in all rows

Tags: jquery

I have a table, and I want get the first “td” in all rows.

My jquery here:

```
$("table.SimpleTable tr td:first-child").css('background-color','red');
```

and my HTML here:

```
<table class='SimpleTable' border="1" ID="Table1">
        <tr>
            <td>Left</td>
            <td>Right</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Left</td>
            <td>Right</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Left</td>
            <td>Right</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Left</td>
            <td>
                <table border="1" ID="Table2">
                    <tr>
                        <td>AAA</td>
                        <td>AAA</td>
                        <td>AAA</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Left</td>
            <td>
                <table border="1" ID="Table3">
                    <tr>
                        <td>BBB</td>
                        <td>BBB</td>
                        <td>BBB</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The problem here it get the first "td" in the nested table of the second "td".

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$("table.SimpleTable > tbody > tr > td:first-child").css(..);
```

`>` only searches in children instead of all descendants. we need `tbody` as browsers insert that into the table.

[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/uRv9C/).

Comment: +1 `tbody`. It's a good idea to add an explicit `<tbody>` to the markup too, to make it clear what's happening and ensure it will still work if you ever serve it as XHTML.

Comment: @bobby if this worked for you, you can mark the answer as "accepted" using the check mark symbol to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Normal CSS selectors will work, you were almost spot on. First `td` in a nested `table` would be

```
$('table table tr td:first-child');
```

To limit the selection only to the second table would be:

```
$('table table tr td:first-child').filter(':nth(1)');
```

[Live example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XN9YN/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select immediate/direct children, try this:

```
$("table.SimpleTable > tr td:first-child").css('background-color','red');
```

The `>` allows you to target only the immediate elements